# Error while generating cubic splines for image processing in MATLAB - "data sites should be distinct"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, spline, numerical-analysis

I'm developing an image processing program in MATLAB. One part of it involves sampling some points at fixed intervals from the input image (which is basically a *binary line drawing* with *1-pixel-wide edges*, similar to those made by the "pencil" tool in Paint / GIMP / Photoshop), and then generating a cubic spline with the sampled pixels as its knots.

Now, I know how to generate a cubic spline in MATLAB given a set of `(x, y)` points, but the problem is this: an image is not a true *function* of `x` (say `x` is the row number of the pixel), because it may have multiple "values" at each x - the values being the numbers of all columns in that row that are black. Because of this MATLAB's `spline()` function complains that "the data sites should be distinct."

How do I get around this?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994054/curve-fitting-unsorted-points-on-a-plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest converting your function to parametric form and then doing two splines, on `x` and `y`:

```
   y = f(x) =>   

   y(t),x(t)
```

In Matlab you can do it in the following way:

```
  t=1:numel(x);
  xs = interp1(t,x, ti);
  ys = interp1(t,y, ti);
```

Where `xi` and `yi` are the points that you want to interpolate.

---

Here is an example with data that has multiple `y` values per `x`:
[image]

```
y = -10:10;
x = y.^2;
figure;plot(x,y,'rv');

t = 1:numel(x);
ti = 1:0.05:numel(x);
xi = interp1(t,x,ti );
yi = interp1(t,y,ti );

hold on ;plot(xi,yi);
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to suffice for my current needs. As a side-effect I finally understood _why_ the hell parametric forms are important :). We just sort of learnt about them as part of our syllabus a few years ago, but nobody cared to tell us where they'd be useful.